# Wiki’s explanation of the rate of chemical reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics, reactivity

Could you please help me understand the Wiki’s explanation of the rate of chemical reaction?

> It says: the rate of the chemical reaction is directly proportional to the product of the activities or concentrations of the reactants.

I can’t wrap my head around this statement. Could anyone explain it in other words please?

Comment: Simply put, if your reaction is A+B, then it is [A]*[B].

Comment: Still not ringing a bell... lets say, that the sum of concentration of reactants is 200 mmol/l. How is this value relevant to the rate of reaction?

Comment: It isn't.$\mathstrut$

Comment: If I understood it correctly, this is applied in kinetic reactions: v=k*[A]*[B]....does the explanation only mean that the speed of reaction depends on the conc of reactants because when they are higher, the reaction rate is higher? or am i missing something?

Comment: Not only that, but it says _how exactly_ rate depends on concentrations.

Comment: Is it basically saying that concentrations of reactants is gonna influnce the speed of reactions in reactions with higher order number (order 0 isnt affected)

Comment: The quoted statement is only true if the reactants are directly reacting in an elementary step.

Comment: [Wiki ≠ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_abbreviate_%22Wikipedia%22_as_%22Wiki%22!). Also, the URL to the target article is missing, and questions like this are usually getting closed as opinion based since it is essentially a request to digest studying material. This corresponds to the cognition, not chemistry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rate of a reaction, or how fast reactants become products, depends on the collisions of particles. This is because when a particle collides, the reaction occurs (provided that it has enough KE). So, if we increase the amount of particles (the concentration), we will have more collisions and therefore the reaction will go by faster.